# is it possible to use multiple certificates for a single web site in IIS

Tags: security, iis, certificate, web-publishing

I want to create a website which connect to different servers using different certificates. is it possible to use multiple certificates for the same website using IIS or any thing to host internally within the organisation. if it is possible what could be the steps involved in this process.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? Do you want to use multiple SSL server certificates on one IIS? Or do you want to use multiple SSL client certificates to connect to different servers from one web site deployed on IIS?

Comment: @pepo multiple SSL client certificates to connect to different servers from one web site deployed on IIS

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can select as many certificates as you wish from certificates store in code and use them to connect to different servers. You just have to ensure that this site (its app pool user) has rights to access private keys of the certificates you wish to use.

Comment: @pepo and how to use multiple SSL server certificates on one IIS

Comment: The feature is called [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). You can make multiple bindings on port 443 with different dns names. But it can not be set in all versions of IIS. [Here](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability) is a list.